# How to use pod in aggregate target's build phase?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, target

I have target `Main` and aggregate target `Script`. `Main` target contains all files and installed pods. `Script` target contains only one build phase:

[image]

When I build target, it don't find pods. I tried to install in Podfile like

```
target 'Script' do
    pod 'Periphery', '= 2.14.1'
end
```

but it return error that aggregate target is not target and can't find it: `Unable to find a target named "Script" in project`

Copied from https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11972#issuecomment-1614373016

Update: structure looks like Project `Main` and two targets in it:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about your current project setup/structure/files.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate target may contain a custom Run Script build phase or a Copy Files build phase, but it cannot contain any other build phases. Any build settings that the aggregate target contains are not interpreted but are passed to the build phases that the target contains.

Xcode defines a special type of target that lets you build a group of targets at once, even if those targets do not depend on each other. An aggregate target has no associated product and no build rules. Instead, an aggregate target depends on each of the targets you want to build together. For example, you may have a group of products that you want to build together. You would create an aggregate target and make it depend on each of the product targets. To build all the products, just build the aggregate target.